# How to get an item inside an HTML Element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am using beautiful soup to collect data from HTML.

I need help to get the data inside `'class': 'Profile-userFullName-_EP'`

Here is my trial to get the `First Last name` from the current HTML.

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.website.com'
r= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
name = soup.find_all('h1', {'class': 'Profile-userFullName-_EP'})

print(name)
```

My current output is:

```
[<h1 class="Profile-userFullName-_EP">First Last name</h1>]
```

My required output when I print name is:

```
First Last name
```

Comment: [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Comment: `[i.text.strip() for i in name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find_all()` returns an array, therefor `name` is an array.

To get the innerHTML of the first element in the `name` array you can do this:

`innerHTML= name[0].decode_contents()`

`print(innerHTML)`

Should print:

`First Last name`